# Polymer styling of elements with custom class doesn't work when vulcanized

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to make a global theme for a polymer app.

I've defined some variables inside a theme file like this.

```
#global-theme.html
<style is="custom-style">

:root {
    --default-primary-color: #00BBD3;
    --primary-background-color: #FFF;
}

:root paper-button.primary {
    color: var(--primary-background-color);
    background-color: var(--default-primary-color);
}

</style>
```

Then in another element I use a `paper-button` with the `.primary` class... but no `.primary` class style is applied.

```
<paper-button class="primary" id="search" on-click="onSearch">Search</paper-button>
```

If I just put `paper-button.primary` definition in a *normal* .css file then it works except that I obviously can't use the variables when it's not inside the polymer system which defeats the purpose.

**This all works fine when in development but doesn't work when vulcanized for production**

How do I define the global styles correctly so that any `paper-button` with `.primary` class has my custom styles applied from within the `custom-style` definition that also works when vulcanized?

----- update -----

I've looked into my vulcanized html file (that is built with the default yeoman/polymer starter kit gulp tasks) and replaced my custom styles that were flattened there with a link to the actual element like `<link rel="import" href="../custom/my-polymer-theme/my-polymer-theme.html">` it works!!

Why would flattening/vulcanization cause this to happen when it's exactly the same code and how would I get around it?

---- FIXED ----

Problem was a boundary between a mixin & variable when vulcanized...

```
:root {
  /* dark theme mixin */
  --dark-theme-colors: {
   color: #fff;
   background-color: var(--secondary-text-color);
 };

 --dark-theme-secondary-text-color: var(--divider-color); 
 ...
}
```

When this was flattened to vulcanized html file it doesn't work any more.

To fix it was as simple as closing off the `:root` bracket and opening a new one.